# Parsing Lint Errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lint

A while back I wrote a blog on [using lint in eclipse](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-lint-in-eclipse-with-netburner.html), now I would like to finally get the error parsing to work so that I can click on the lint info/warning/error line and have it jump to that location in code. There seem to be a couple of standard approaches but I can't get them to work. I'm open to a general answer or a specific answer to one of the questions below.

1. Using a makefile instead of an external tool. I used managed builds but I've gotten close and now in my managed build I have a configuration that attempts to run lint instead of doing a build. The only problem is that something in Eclipse keeps adding the "-k" option to the command, which causes lint to fail. Does anyone know how to keep Eclipse from adding that -k option? (If I delete it, it just comes back).[image: screen shot showing the -k option]
2. The other approach is to parse the output to the console window. I [found a plug-in](http://sunshade.sourceforge.net/) called ErrorLink that seemed perfect. Unfortunately, either I can't construct a conforming regular expression or I'm not configuring the tool to run correctly for lint. The rather sparse directions say to add your exe to the .xml file. I found the xml file and added

   `<consoleLineTracker class="net.sourceforge.sunshade.errorlink.RegexpLineTracker" processType="lint-nt" id="regexpLineTracker"`>`</consoleLineTracker`>

Then I tried a simple regex like (SomeFileName`.cpp)  where I made sure SomeFileName.cpp showed up in the results, but no links are generated. I can't tell if the ErrorLink plug-in actually ran but I'm guessing it didn't. So has anyone ever used this plug-in? Any hints on how to get it to work with lint?

Comment: Well, I didn't get any answers but I got a **tumbleweed** badge, LOL.

Comment: In the reply I marked as the answer below, clearing the "clean" check box seems to have worked. This problem came up again today Friday the 13th 2012 and that solution didn't help. Turning ON the "Stop on first build error" on the behavior tab makes the -k option disappear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to the Behaviour Tab, uncheck "clean", add your lint options there (that solved this issue for me)
2. Go to:
   Menu-bar: Window | Preferences
   navigation tree: C/C++ | Build
   choose the tab: "Error Parsers"

   Click "Add" right to the parser list, and name it like "my Funky PCLint RegEX" and select it

   Click "Add" in the "Error Parser Options" box below

For example a non perfect List

- Severity: Info
- Pattern: (.*) ([0-9]*): Error -> Info (.*)
- File: $1
- Line: $2
- Description: $3

and
 - Severity: Warning
 - Pattern: (.*) ([0-9]*): Error -> Warning (.*)
 - File: $1
 - Line: $2
 - Description: $3

Warning and Info are pretty mouch the same. anyone tweaking the regex is welcome.

Comment: Well thank goodness for people that read old questions. I marked this as the answer for item 1 above (so simple but so elusive). I would like to follow step 2 also but I can't find what you specified. I don't have a **Window|Properties** - I have a Window|**Preferences** and a **Project**|Properties but, I can't find Build|Error Parsers under either one. Under Project|Properties|C/C++ Build - the content pane on the right has an Error Parsers tab so this looks like what you mean but I don't see a way to "add" a parser.  Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, i did mix up things a bit, the "Error Parsers" tab is exactly what you're looking for, but in window | preferences! gonna edit the response.